# Efficient 3d signed angle calculation in Python using arctan2

Tags: python, numpy, vector, 3d

I'm working with 2 vector arrays (shape = (100, 3)) and a tangent vector array (also shape = (100, 3)) and want to get the most efficient way to properly get the signed angle between the vectors, given the tangent vector orthogonal to both vectors. I've seen this solved for 2d on stackoverflow, but not 3d using arctan2. I need to use arctan2 rather than acos due to potential small angles. I have a custom function to calculate the norm of the cross product along the correct axes (called normrow), but in calculating the sine angle using the norm, I lose the sign information. What's the most efficient way to keep the correct sign on my sine angles so arctan2 returns the correct value between -pi and pi?

```
from numpy import cross, reshape, einsum

def v_angle(v1, v2, tangent):
        cos_ang = einsum('ij, ij -> i', v1, v2).reshape(-1, 1)
        sin_ang  = normrow(cross(v1, v2))
        return arctan2(sin_ang, cos_ang))
```

Is the best way to take the sign of the dot product of the cross product and tangent vector? I've tried it 2 ways, and the second is marginally faster.

```
from numpy import cross, reshape, einsum, sign, arctan2
import time

numvec = 10000000

v1 = zeros((numvec, 3), dtype=float64)
v2 = zeros((numvec, 3), dtype=float64)
tangent = zeros((numvec, 3), dtype=float64)
v1[:, 1] = 1.0
v2[:, 1] = 0.5
v2[:, 2] = sqrt(3) / 2.
tangent[:, 0] = 1.0

def v_angle_signed(v1, v2, tangent):
    cos_ang = einsum('ij, ij -> i', v1, v2).reshape(-1, 1)
    sin_ang  = normrow(cross(v1, v2))
    sign_sin = sign(einsum('ij, ij -> i', cross(v1,v2), tangent)).reshape(-1, 1)
    sin_ang *= sign_sin
    return arctan2(sin_ang, cos_ang)

def v_angle_signed_v2(v1, v2, tangent):
    cosang = einsum('ij, ij -> i', v1, v2).reshape(-1, 1)
    cross_p = cross(v1, v2)
    sinang = sign(einsum('ij, ij -> i', cross_p, tangent)).reshape(-1, 1) * normrow(cross_p)
    return arctan2(sinang, cosang)

tick = time.time()
angle = v_angle(v1, v2)
print('wrong sign %.5f' % (time.time()-tick) + 's')
tick = time.time()
angle2 = v_angle_signed(v1, v2, tangent)
print('correct sign v1 %.5f' % (time.time()-tick) + 's')
tick = time.time()
angle3 = v_angle_signed_v2(v1, v2, tangent)
print('correct sign v2 %.5f' % (time.time()-tick) + 's')
```

For a sample size of 10,000,000:

```
Output:
wrong sign 1.20736s
correct sign v1 1.97774s
correct sign v2 1.38374s
```

Comment: Have you tried timing your two approaches?

Comment: you don't use 'tangent' ?

Comment: @Eric, updated to include timing. The original posting did not have the correct sign on the first function (v_angle).

Comment: You should use the `timeit` module to produce those